# Debugging Error in VBA Code

Tags: vba

I have the following code that adds zeroes to a number until the number is a total of 7 digits long. It was worked fine up until now, the code is:

```
Sub AddZeroes()
'Declarations
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, endrow As Long
'Converts the A column format to Text format
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
'finds the bottom most row
endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'selects the top cell in column A
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

'loop to move from cell to cell
For i = 1 To endrow - 1
            'Moves the cell down 1. Assumes there's a header row so really starts at row 2
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            'The Do-While loop keeps adding zeroes to the front of the cell value until it     hits     a length of 7
Do While Len(ActiveCell.Value) < 7
                            ActiveCell.Value = "0" & ActiveCell.Value
            Loop
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code loops through the A column and if a number does not have 7 total numbers it adds 0s to the beginning. THe error is appearing at the portion of code

```
FOR I = 1 TO ENDROW - 1
```

I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong. This portion tells the macro that once it reaches the end of the list to find the blank space and move up 1 so it stops on the last number, and it has worked up until today.

Comment: so what is the error ?

Comment: I added that in the end

Comment: What is the error? Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: what is the value of `i` when this error happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an integer value for `i` which is likely causing an overflow in that variable.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddZeroes()
'Declarations
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Long, endrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Converts the A column format to Text format
        Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
        'finds the bottom most row
        endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        '## Or, for Excel 2003 and prior: ##'
        'endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        'loop to move from cell to cell
        For i = 1 To endrow - 1
            Set cl = Range("A" & i)
            With cl
            'The Do-While loop keeps adding zeroes to the front of the cell value until it     hits     a length of 7
                Do While Len(.Value) < 7
                    .Value = "0" & .Value
                Loop
            End With
        Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That is exactly what was causing it, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked!  Note some revisions to the rest of your code, too. Try to avoid things like `Select` and `ActiveCell` whenever possible (99.9% of the time). :)  Usually these constructs are not at all necessary.